# Coalesce with no preference to order

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I have 3 columns I'm trying to move into 1.  In each row, exactly only 1 of the 3 will be populated.  For example:

```
**col1 | col2 | col3**  
 10    | null | null  
 null  | 15   | null  
 null  | null | 9  
 22    | null | null  
 null  | 2    | null  
 17    | null | null
```

I want to now coalesce all the columns into one.
First off, is that the best way to do it?

Secondly, is there a way to specify to COALESCE() whether or not the order of arguments matters?

edit: final result should be:

```
col1  
----  
10  
15  
9  
22  
2  
17
```

Comment: What will the final result look like?

Comment: Not sure what you need, please explain with example and expected results

Comment: "is that the best way to do it" ? Is **what** the best way to do it?

Comment: What is wrong with just `SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) AS col FROM table` ?

Comment: And no, there is no way to tell COALESCE that the order of the arguments does not matter as it is specifically documented and coded to return the first non-null argument. The question is why you would need it for this question here.

Comment: @Horaciux I just wanted to know if this was an appropriate use of coalesce, and whether or not there was another way that had no preference to the order of the arguments.

Comment: Since you stated that only one column will be non-null, why does it matter that COALESCE uses first-non-null ordering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(v) 
        FROM (VALUES (col1), (col2), (col3)) AS x(v))
FROM mytable
```

The above query uses [**Table Value Constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) in order to build an inline table with all three table columns. Applying `MAX` on this table returns the non-null value.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6076f5/1)

**Edit:**

It seems you can get at the required result with a simple use of [**COALESCE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) AS col
FROM mytable
```

The `COALESCE` expression will return the value of the *first* not-null field.

Comment: Why not just use `COALESCE` as the OP hints at? `SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) AS col FROM mytable` should do the trick.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Well, yes you are right. I over complicated things.

Comment: You could also add it as a persisted calculated column so you don't need to figure it out each time you need the data:

`ALTER TABLE mytable ADD ACTUAL_VALUE AS COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) PERSISTED`